# Can't create a bug work item in my devops board

Tags: azure-devops

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTG2j.png)

I don't know why but the project doesn't let me create bugs or history work items. Can it be because its a free account?

Answer (score 0):

Your project is set to Basic Process. You can change the process of your project or create custom work item from your Azure DevOps settings page. But, to be able to create custom work item, you need to create a subprocess from the base process you like : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/manage-process?view=azure-devops

You can refer to the Microsoft Documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/guidance/choose-process?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process